# Iterating through multiple arguments in a function?

Tags: python

How would I go about iterating through this function so that it tries all possible combinations where **a**, **b**, **c**, **d** are a range of numbers where:

**a** = 20 to 40, **b** = 80 to 100, **c** = 100 to 120, **d** = 120 to 140

```
def euler(a,b,c,d):
    my_dict = {'A1':[],'A2':[],'A3':[],'A4':[],'Number': []}
    y = a**5 + b**5 + c**5 + d**5
    for n in range(140,161):
        if n**5 == y:
            my_dict['A1'].append(a)
            my_dict['A2'].append(b)
            my_dict['A3'].append(c)
            my_dict['A4'].append(d)
            my_dict["Number"].append(n)
            return my_dict  
        else:
            pass
```

Essentially I want to iterate through all combinations to find a match between **a** **b** **c** and **d**.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: or `itertools.product()` as I don't really think `.combinations()` is what you are after given you have differing lists to combine.

Comment: @JonSG You're right, I was too quick to comment lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Here's a slightly optimized version by precomputing the 5th power of each number and removing unreachable values of `n`. (Original version down below)

```py
from itertools import product

def euler(a, b, c, d):
    y = A5[a] + B5[b] + C5[c] + D5[d]
    if y in N:
        n = N.index(y) + 140
        my_dict = {'A1': [], 'A2': [], 'A3': [], 'A4': [], 'Number': []}
        my_dict['A1'].append(a)
        my_dict['A2'].append(b)
        my_dict['A3'].append(c)
        my_dict['A4'].append(d)
        my_dict["Number"].append(n)
        return my_dict

# generate lists of numbers to iterate
A = list(range(20, 41))
B = list(range(80, 101))
C = list(range(100, 121))
D = list(range(120, 141))

# precompute 5th powers of a, b, c, d
A5 = {a: a**5 for a in A}
B5 = {b: b**5 for b in B}
C5 = {c: c**5 for c in C}
D5 = {d: d**5 for d in D}

# precompute 5th powers of n, removing unreachable values
N = [n**5 for n in range(140, 161) if n**5 <= 40**5 + 100**5 + 120**5 + 140**5]

for a, b, c, d in product(A, B, C, D):
    if res:= euler(a, b, c, d):
        print(res)
```

**Original:** Here's a simple implementation (thanks to @JonSG, it was `product`, not `combinations`!)

```py
from itertools import product

def euler(a,b,c,d):
    my_dict = {'A1':[],'A2':[],'A3':[],'A4':[],'Number': []}
    y = a**5 + b**5 + c**5 + d**5
    for n in range(140,161):
        if n**5 == y:
            my_dict['A1'].append(a)
            my_dict['A2'].append(b)
            my_dict['A3'].append(c)
            my_dict['A4'].append(d)
            my_dict["Number"].append(n)
            return my_dict  
        else:
            pass

A = range(20, 41)
B = range(80, 101)
C = range(100, 121)
D = range(120, 141)

for a, b, c, d in product(A, B, C, D):
    res = euler(a, b, c, d)
    if res:
        print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation you want is the *cartesian product*. `itertools.product` is a function you can use

```py
for a, b, c in itertools.product(range(20,40), range(80, 100), range(100, 120)
```

(however, the number of combinations get impractical very fast, and maybe you need another approach)